# TypeMismatch error in filling List from JSON

Tags: json, swift

i am trying to fill a list from JSON in SwiftUI, which has this format:

```
    {
    "books": [{
        "id": "87",
        "title": "2001 odissea nello spazio",
        "author_id": null,
        "author": "arthur c. clarke",
        "editor_id": null,
        "editor": "longanesi",
        "price": "0.00",
        "isbn": "",
        "note": ""
    }, ......]
}
```

i created this struct for the Book object:

```
struct Book: Decodable, Identifiable {

    public var id: Int;
    public var title: String;
    public var isbn: String;

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id";
        case title = "title";
        case isbn = "isbn";
    }

}
```

then i created this class to get the remote json:

```
import Foundation

    public class GetBooks: ObservableObject {

        @Published var books = [Book]();

        init() {
            load();
        }

        func load() {
            let url = URL(string: "https://www.mattepuffo.com/api/book/get.php")!;

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
                (data, response, error) in
                do {
                    if let d = data {
                        let decodedLists = JSONDecoder();
                        decodedLists.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase;
                        let dec = try decodedLists.decode([Book].self, from: d);
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.books = dec;
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("Non ci sono libri");
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }

            }.resume();

        }
    }
```

but i get an error: **typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))**

I think I understand what the problem is, but I don't understand how to solve it.
in the sense that the problem is that the json starts with an object (books) and not with an array.
but I don't understand how I have to modify the code!

I also tried to modify this line in this way, getting the error you see in the comment:

```
let dec = try decodedLists.decode(Book.self, from: d);
DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.books = dec; // Cannot assign value of type 'Book' to type '[Book]'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your JSON is not an `Array` of `Book`.

You need an upper level struct:

```
struct BookList: Decodable {
    let books : [Book]
}
```

and then decode this structure instead of the array:

```
let dec = try decodedLists.decode(BookList.self, from: d);
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.books = dec.books;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two major issues in your code:

1. You are ignoring the root object of the JSON, the dictionary with key `books`. This causes the error.
2. The type of key `id` is a string, in JSON **everything** in double quotes is `String`.

Further you don't need `CodingKeys` if all struct member names match the JSON keys and if the struct members are not going to be modified declare them as constants (`let`). Finally this is Swift: No trailing *objective-c-ish* semicolons.

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    public let books: [Book]
}

struct Book: Decodable, Identifiable {

    public let id: String
    public let title: String
    public let isbn: String
}
```

---

```
let result = try decodedLists.decode(Root.self, from: d)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.books = result.books
}
```

Comment: thanks for correcting the id field, in fact I hadn't thought of that!